# Reading From Google Sheets Periodically

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to read from a Google sheet say every 2 hours.  I have looked at both the API for Google sheets and also the Google Apps Script.

I'm using Python/Flask, and what I'm specifically confused about is how to add the time trigger. I can use the Google Sheets API to read from the actual file,but I'm unsure of how to run this process every x hours. From my understanding,  it seems like Google Apps Script, is for adding triggers to doc, sheets, etc, which is not really what I want to do.

I'm pretty sure I'm looking in the wrong area for this x hour read. Should I be looking into using the sched module or Advanced Python Scheduler?Any advice on how to proceed would be very appreciated.

Comment: I use Django and I've written a Django command in python that I have then scheduled to run daily using Linux cron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this with only manipulating your Python program, you would have to run it all day. This would waste CPU resources.

It's best to use cron to schedule your unix system to run a command for you every 2 hours. In this case, it'd be your python program.